# Angular Testbed: avoid module setup in each test module

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am using angular 3rd party component library. The library contains widgets based on webcomponents. It takes around 3 seconds until all the webcomponents are registered.

I have to `await` till the library is ready and then go on with the actual test. I need to `import` this library basically in every test module which means the above mentioned setup takes place many times and massively slows down testing.

Is there a way to setup the library once for all tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ordinary Angular project created with Angular CLI, you should have the `src/test.ts` file. It runs before all the tests. Nice place for a setup you described.

If you wonna get fancy, you can setup the build configuration for tests in the Angular.json with a `main` file containing the setup you need.

```json
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",
....
  }
},
```